# Why does partition table corruption even happen?

Tags: partitioning, live-cd, ntfs

I created an extended partition and tried to add two NTFS units to it. Instead two 125 GB partitions, I got – according to Disk Utility – 2 X 982 GB partitions plus a [14574534 TB one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpJux.png) (wahey!). I don't remember to have done anything weird.

The case is:

- Neither Disk Utility, GParted or fdisk will let me fix/delete the extended partition, and in addition,
- My LiveCD won't boot, although the BIOS order is correct and it worked perfectly before Ubuntu was installed. The hard drive installation of Ubuntu will start instead (**edit** – I got it to boot but having the drive unmounted does not fix the issue).

I guess I could try even more tools but I don't think this is that much of an unusual problem... what's the straight-forward solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cosmic background radiation. No joke. Per second in an area of your hand approx. 10 high energetic particles hit. If they decay there, they can reverse bits. It's a wonder pcs even work from time to time. But in your case - more likely a software bug. That error sounds familiar.

Comment: Well at least you can actually download the whole internet and sync with everyone.

Comment: You own a very special kind of business-class HDD, meant for politicians and CEOs. It has virtually unlimited "budget", but its definately corrupted :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I managed to fix this, but in a pretty heterodox way I think.

As I said, my problem in particular consisted in an extended, infinisized-yet-empty, useless partition that couldn't be deleted with any of the usually recommended GNU tools for these cases.

It could be deleted with the Windows 7 installer. However, this messes up the whole partition table so you need to recover it using testdisk (no, I couldn't do this before the delete).

After this, you need to recover your GRUB with a CD or so.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this may help you.
http://tutafuta.com/2011/03/15/partition-table-repair-reinstall-copy-for-future/

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't...

Answer (score 2):

If the CD doesnt work did you try to create a live usb stick and start a session using the usb stick?

Comment: I finally got the CD to work (well, it started to do for no good reason) but this isn't allowing me to delete the partition :(